# Vertical scroll bar problem

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

http://smiths-heimann.az/?page=7&id=1&subid=1 check this out. Where's the end arrow of vertical scroll bar? http://prntscr.com/2hleg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update the "#container" container by making `padding-bottom: 183px`; and you will be able to see the end of the scroll.

Also update the ".content" style by making `padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px`;

Answer (score 1):

Remove overflow from `#container`:

```
#container { 
min-width: 980px;
/* overflow-x: auto; */
/* overflow-y: auto; */
padding-bottom: 100px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Agree, your question is a little short, but certainly not wrong. +1

Answer (score 1):

Update your style with the following and the scroll will be shown:

```
#container {
    clear: left;
    min-width: 980px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```